# Windows 7 and missing patches and how to handle

Tags: windows, vulnerability, updates, patching

With the ransomware scare, someone asked me to look at their computer to make sure they have the required patch.  They had no patches after June 2016, with only the recent May 2017 patches installed.  I installed the security only for March, but wondering the best way to proceed to have their Windows 7 Home Premium fully patched.  Since they have May 2017, if I manually install patches missing from June 2016, will it overwrite possible patches installed with the May 2017?

I am not sure why Windows is not recognizing that they are missing the patches.  I could just install the security only from October 2016 to April 2017, and see what critical patches were released from July to September, but my concern is how will this effect May 2017 patches.

Also, just an fyi.  Windows is working in that it checks for updates and had the May 2017 to install and updated successfully with the May 2017.

Comment: Did you try to install "Windows 7 SP1 Convenience Rollups"  ?(https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3125574/convenience-rollup-update-for-windows-7-sp1-and-windows-server-2008-r2-sp1 and  https://support.microsoft.com/en-za/help/3172605/july-2016-update-rollup-for-windows-7-sp1-and-windows-server-2008-r2-sp1)

Answer (score 5):

Windows security patches are now cumulative which means that each new patch should contain the previous month's security fixes.

If you have any of the following patches installed you should be safe.

- May, 2017 Security Monthly Quality Rollup for Windows 7 (KB4019264)
- April, 2017 Preview of Monthly Quality Rollup for Windows 7 (KB4015552)
- April, 2017 Security Monthly Quality Rollup for Windows 7 (KB4015549)
- March, 2017 Security Monthly Quality Rollup for Windows 7 (KB4012215)
- March, 2017 Security Only Quality Update for Windows 7 (KB4012212)